# METRO UI CSS ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, metro-ui-css

i want to use METRO UI CSS in my app:

1. Create ASP NET MVC Project
2. I downloaded METRO UI MVC by:

`Package Manager Console: PM> Install-Package Metro.UI.CSS`

3. Change bundles to this image:

   ```
           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                           "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                           "~/Scripts/metro-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js",
                           "~/Scripts/metro-ui/metro.min.js"
                           ));

           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                       "~/Scripts/metro-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"
                       ));

           // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
           // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                     "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

           bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                     //"~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                     //"~/Content/site.css",
                     "~/Content/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap.css",
                     "~/Content/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css",
                     "~/Content/metro-ui/css/iconFont.min.css"));
       }
   ```

my head of _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <link href="Content/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/metro.min.js"></script>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/metro-ui/css")

</head>
```

before end of the body i have:

```
   <body class="metro">
      (...)
      @RenderBody()

      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/metro-ui")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
      @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body>
</html>
```

My part of the **solution explorer** looks like:

[image]

and for example in View for controller: Home, action: Index

http://pastebin.com/7UXbWhBQ

result:
[image]
and when i click on the list (f.e Base CSS) nothing happen...

here's the documentation:
https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/blob/master/docs/navbar.html

**what's wrong?**

Comment: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` renders the 3 scripts included in the bundle so remove the duplicated from the `<head>`. You do not appear to have bundles for `@Styles.Render("~/Content/metro-ui/css")` or `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/metro-ui")`

Comment: it's work! please add the answer and i can check it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are duplicating scripts and referring to non existent bundles. This line

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

renders the 3 scripts included in you bundle definition so remove the corresponding scripts from the `<head>` section.

You also have `@Styles.Render("~/Content/metro-ui/css")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/metro-ui")`. Neither of these bundles exist in your `BundleConfig.cs` file